Name of TV show about the presidents' dogs from around the world?
It was a cartoon show about the presidents' dogs from around the world and they would secretly fight crime and that sort of thing. It was in the US on WB or Cartoon Network I believe and was aired in the late 1990s or early 2000s I think.  I think the dogs were from Russia, US, England and France possibly.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

updated the description, thanks for the feedback

I believe you're looking for the 1996-97 Cartoon Network (one-season) show Road Rovers:

The show follows the adventures of the Road Rovers, a team of five super-powered crime-fighting anthropomorphic dogs, known as "cano-sapiens".
In the town of Socorro, New Mexico (one year prior to the formation of the Road Rovers), Professor Shepherd forced to relinquish experimental transdogmafier technology to General Parvo in exchange for his lost dog, but instead Parvo gives him a bomb that destroys his laboratory. Next year, as normal dogs begin to mutate into monsters, Shephard, who miraculously survived the attack, takes measures to stop Parvo who is behind this.
Shepherd selects five different dogs and in his new, secret underground lab, he uses his new transdogmifier on the five, turning them into "Cano-sapiens".

The dogs were each from a different country including the US, UK, Germany, Siberia, and Switzerland.
Here's the opening theme:



